# need signalR polling for asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-ajax

Any kind soul can guide me how to use signalR on an existing mvc project to poll data in real time i'd be greatly appreciate.
example code:

[controller]

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
public PartialViewResult Chat(string people) // <---need to send real time data to partial
    {
            var model = new MessageVM()
            {      
                sender = User.Identity.Name;,              
                messageList = db.messages.Where(x => x.receiver == people).ToList().Take(30)
            };
            return PartialView("_chat", model);
    }
```

[view]

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.name, "Chat", new { people = item.name }, new AjaxOptions() 
{ HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divChat", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })

<div id="divChat"></div>  // <---this area need real-time messages data from controller.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create your signalr connection in js in client side. something like:

```
    function signalrconnection() {

    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:54321/signalr";
    chat = $.connection.myHub;


    if (chat != undefined) {
        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            chat.server.send("client", "Status\tasking for status");
            chat = $.connection.myHub;
        })
        .fail(function () { NoLTConnectionAlert(); });
    }
    else {
           ///do something.
        }
    }

    return chat;
}
```

Then add signalr call to your `$(document).ready(function ())` in your js something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    chat = signalrconnection();
    intervalstatus = setInterval(checkstatus, 1000);

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {}
}
```

In your controller you should have a class for hub and method inside like:

```
     public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
          Clients.Caller.addMessage("parameter", reply);
        }
    }
```

Then again you should handle `Clients.Caller.addMessage` in you js to update `<div id="divChat"></div>`